# Adjustable column size in paracol

Tags: verse, paracol

I'm using paracol (and verse) to get a poem in two different languages. Some lines are of different lenght in a language or in the other. How can adjust the column size so that the line doesn't get broken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define the `\columnratio` that you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}

\columnratio{0.6}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}

\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the separation between columns modifying the following parameter:

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
```

And this part fixes the justification issue with columns flowing over:

```
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!