# parcolumns page and font style

Tags: parcolumns, awesome-cv

I'm trying to modify the [Awesome-CV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) template in order to make it a 2 column CV. Initially the template for Awesome-CV was setting up something with the structure:

```
---------------------
|   Head            |
---------------------
| cv-text           |
|                   |
|                   |
---------------------

---------------------
|   multiple        |
|     pages         |
|      of           |
|     cv-text       |
---------------------
```

And what I wanted to do is:

```
---------------------
|   Head            |
---------------------
| col 1|  col 2     |
|      |            |
|      |            |
---------------------

---------------------
| multi|  multi     |
| page |   page     |
| col1 |    col2    |
|      |            |
---------------------
```

To this end, I'm trying to use the package `parcolumns` for this end, so I have:

```
\begin{document}
  \makecvheader

  \newcommand{\goesleft}[1]{\colchunk{#1}}
  \newcommand{\goesright}[1]{\colchunk{#1}\colplacechunks}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=0.24\textwidth,2=0.69\textwidth}]{2}
    \goesleft{ \lipsum}
    \goesright{\lipsum}
  \end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

The configuration for the columns work, they appear at the place I want, and they work for multiple pages. **The problem is**: when I put the cv content inside the `parcolumns` environment all the definitions of font, color, and style get mixed up.
Does someone know how can I transmit the color,font, and style configurations from my macro to the `parcolumns` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing some extra research, I think I solved the problem.

The answer to my question is: `parcolumns` does not like when one try to work with different spacing in each of the columns, and that's why it was mixing up my setups for font, style and colour. This problem is explained in detail in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/line-spacing-in-parcolumns-environment)

The thing is: I need it to work with different colour, spacing, font and styles in each column as if they were really independent boxes. So, how can I do that without having problems with different text formation? The answer I found is based on [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/line-spacing-in-parcolumns-environment) and [on this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307569/adjustable-column-size-in-paracol): `paracol` package is "Yet Another Multi-Column Package" and it allows to do what I wanted, which is something like:

```
\usepackage{paracol}

    \begin{document}
      \makecvheader

    \columnratio{0.29} %defines the size of the left column
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      \lipsum    % text for the left column
      \switchcolumn %changes to the right column
      \lipsum    %text for the right column
    \end{paracol}
    \end{document}
```